# Apache 2.4 random chrome ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, web-server, chrome

Firstly, I would like to say I am somewhat a rookie to apache configs. I have worked with it a little bit but definitely not enough to the level of many apache professionals. Due to this, some detailed explanations would be much appreciated.

Over the past few weeks, our website has been randomly outputting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on chrome. It does this for seemingly random resources at random times with no visible consistency. This includes pdf files, php links, and even simple html links. The error seems to be there in one page one day but then disappears the next day or appears in another page the next day.

After researching for a while I have tried the following:

- setting Cache-Control to no-cache
- disabling opcache

and some more tricks that honestly I cannot remember at this point

I don't think I can attach the httpd.conf but here's some further specs I can supply about the webserver:

```
Apache/2.4.56 (Unix) PHP/8.0.30 LibreSSL/3.3.6
Max Requests Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100\
Timeouts Connection: 60 - Keep-Alive: 5 \
Loaded Modules: core mod_so http_core prefork mod_authn_file mod_authn_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_user mod_authz_core mod_access_compat mod_auth_basic mod_cache mod_cache_disk mod_socache_shmcb mod_reqtimeout mod_filter mod_mime mod_log_config mod_env mod_headers mod_setenvif mod_version mod_slotmem_shm mod_ssl mod_unixd mod_status mod_autoindex mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_alias mod_rewrite mod_php mod_hfs_apple2 \
Server Protocol: HTTP/1.1
```

I am very much open to suggestions because I think I have exhausted all of the other internet resources.

Comment: welcome, home and enduser question are offtopic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com instead. Please read carefully [ask] and update the question. In the current point of view it is not on topic

Comment: Can you please please provide your running apache config by `apachectl -S`